# How to fetch nft metadata in anchor program?

Tags: metaplex, nft, metadata

I would like to fetch on-chain metadata of nft such as collection and creators. The function which I used before `Metadata::from_account_info` is missing in the sdk in latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I think that [this](https://docs.rs/mpl-token-metadata/latest/src/mpl_token_metadata/traits.rs.html#80-92) is what's now used in the latest rust client. `Metadata::safe_deserialize`

Comment: I am using `Metadata::try_from` and it's working fine. just have to pass metadata account info.